# PHP Iframe with POST data

Tags: php, post, iframe

I normally use the following iframe code in php.

```
<?php
 $url = "http://mydomain/login.php";
 echo '<iframe ... src="'.urldecode($url).'" width="100%" height="100%" seamless frameborder="0"></iframe>';
?>
```

Here I would like to pass the POST data with name 'User' and 'Password'

Comment: In your iframe php script you should build your application logic

Comment: You have a good answer from @Quentin. Folow his steps

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to load the result of a POST request into an iframe are to:

1. Create a form (containing suitable inputs to pass the data you want)
2. Set the target attribute of the form to the frame
3. Submit the form

and

1. Make the POST request with XMLHttpRequest
2. Edit the content of the frame using DOM manipulation and the data in the response